# prove Fisher's inequality not using matrix method .

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Fisher's inequality, is a necessary condition for the existence of a balanced incomplete block design which satisfies certain prescribed conditions in combinatorial mathematics.

Let:

v : be the number of varieties of plants;

b : be the number of blocks.

It was required that:

k : different varieties are in each block, k < v; no variety occurs twice in any one block;

any two varieties occur together in exactly λ blocks;

each variety occurs in exactly r blocks.

Fisher's inequality states simply that

b >= v

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_inequality#Proof

choose one arbitrary block like B and assume xi is the number of blocks that intersects B at exactly i element.

first QUESTION is how we could show

$\sum_{i}^{k}
x_{i}
\begin{pmatrix}
i\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
k\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}
(\lambda - 1)
$

and

$
\sum_{i}^{k} ix_{i} = k(r - 1)
$

then assume m be the average |B $\cap $ C| on every block C $\neq  $ B so

$m(b - 1) = \sum_{i}^{k} ix_{i}$

Second QUESTION is show

$
\sum_{i}^{k}
x_{i} (i - m)^{2} \geqslant 0
$
implies that

$(b - 1)k(k - 1)(\lambda - 1) + (b - 1)k(r - 1) \geqslant  k ^{2} (r - 1)^{2}$

THIRD  show (r - k)(r - $\lambda$)(v - k)$\geqslant $ 0

I know useing below equality

rv = bk and $\lambda (v - 1) = r(k - 1)$

is helpfull in this step

At the end we see r$\geqslant $k then b$\geqslant $v and Fisher's inequality proved!

which all of that is an exercise on "First course in discrete mathematics" By Ian ANDERSON in design chapter